# How to upload a file into Firestore in Angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with an angular project as well as I want to upload a file for `firestorage`. `create` is a component of my project.

**create.component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="featuredPhotoSelected($event)" />
```

**create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-create',
    templateUrl: './create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create.component.scss']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

What should I do for this thing.

Comment: firebase storage or firestore?